# How do I sort a list of strings, where one specific value should be last despite default sort order?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am trying to Sort list of String in C#. Have an option called 'TBD' in the list. I want to display the  'TBD' String to be displayed in the last.

Example list: "Orange, Apple, TBD, Mango, WaterMelon, Zucchini"

Expected list: "Apple, Mango, Orange, WaterMelon, Zucchini, TBD"

I am using the `CompareTo()` method to sort the list of strings.

```
str1.ToLower().CompareTo(str2.ToLower());
```

Is there any other methods to achieve the same?

Comment: keep some id for each items, and sort based on the ID.

Comment: @adminSoftDK [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx): "*This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture.*" Don't think. Know.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ok, I took the misleading comment out :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ:

```
list = list.OrderBy(str => str == "TBD").ThenBy(str => str).ToList();
```

It works because `true`(1) is greater than  `false`(0).

if you want to compare case-insensitively:

```
list = list
    .OrderBy(str => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(str, "TBD"))
    .ThenBy(str => str, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToList();
```